# How to join array values in PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP array:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'cid' => string '18427' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array
      'cid' => string '17004' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array
      'cid' => string '19331' (length=5)
```

I want to join the values so I can get a string like this:

```
18427,17004,19331
```

I tried the `implode` PHP function, But I get an error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
```

How can join only the values which are in `cid`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to map the array values first:

```
echo join(',', array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['cid'];
}, $arr));
```

Without [closures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) it would look like this:

```
function get_cid($item)
{
  return $item['cid'];
}

echo join(',', array_map('get_cid', $arr));
```

See also: [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map)

Comment: @Jack.. Thanks for the solution and it worked. But there's a small error in the code `$arr` needs to be inside the function for the solution with the closures.. :)

Comment: `array_column()`

Comment: ah yeah, indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// set a new variable for their the value of cid
$cid = array();

// then loop to call them one by one.
foreach($css as $style){
 foreach($style as $row){
    array_push($cid,$row);
 }
}

// then the new $cid array would contain the values of your cid array
 $cid = array('1','2','3');
```

*note:then you can now implode or watever you want to get the data set you want..*

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through each element

```
$result = '';
foreach($array as $sub_array){
  $result .= $sub_array['cid'] . ',';
  }
$result = substr($result, -2);
```